# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails from php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working with a php file where I am giving input to the database. and the database is giving the following error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`amaradmission`.`login`, CONSTRAINT `fk_login_students1` FOREIGN KEY (`students_idstudents`) REFERENCES `students` (`idstudents`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

here is the php file:

```
<?php
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $host='localhost';
  $user='root';
  $pass='';
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("amaradmission",$con);
  $passingyear = $_GET['passingYear'];
  $board= $_GET['board'];
  $gpa = $_GET['gpa'];
  $group = $_GET['group'];


  //$data = array($passingyear, $board,$gpa, $group);  
  //echo json_encode($data);

  $query="INSERT INTO hsc(board,passing_year,gpa,hsc_group) VALUES('$board','$passingyear','$gpa','$group');";

  if(mysql_query($query))
  {
     echo "I am here";
  }else{
   echo  mysql_error();
  }

 //}

  ?>
```

Screen shot of the table where the problem exists
[image]
Screen shot of the parent table
[image: parent table of the previous table]
Mysql workbench structure image
[image: mysql workbench structure]

php file is in the server side. Server is receiving information using JS file. php file is getting all the correct value but I am unable to insert in the database due to foreign key issue. I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I have added the image of the db structure as well. i also added the MySQL workbench structure and parent table screen shot. I am really confused on how to insert data when foreign key exist in the table.

Thank you.

Comment: How about `SELECT`ing values first to check if they exist and then act accordingly (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `REPLACE`)?

Comment: I did and values do exist,

Comment: I'm sorry, I've somewhat misread your question - in your case `FOREIGN KEY` fails, it means that you're referencing value that does not exist in other table.

Comment: I am checking that. thanks

Comment: ... and it is impossible to tell what the parent table is and what foreign key constraint on the table you're inserting into refers to from that PhpMyAdmin screenshot ... seeing the SHOW CREATE output for table 'hsc' would help a bit, SHOW CREATE for the parent table even more so ...

Comment: blind educated guess: either the `board` or `hsc_group` that's being referred to doesn't exist yet ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe, I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Please show the CREATE TABLE statements, not just screenshots of ER diagrams ... 

The error message is pretty clear though:

`[...] FOREIGN KEY (students_idstudents) REFERENCES students (idstudents) [...]`

There's a column namend students_idstudents that refers to students.idstudents, and you're not providing a value for that ...

The column is not necessarily visible in the Workbench ER diagram as Workbench may have added it implicitly when creating the link to the student table, but it is there and needs to be filled for sure

Comment: On the other hand there is no such column in the PhpMyAdmin screenshot for the table ... please run
`
    SHOW CREATE TABLE students;
    SHOW CREATE TABLE hsdc;
` 
and provide us with the output. There will be too much guessing otherwise ...